# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

debugger tells me there's a ; missing before the statement at the line with personSrv.getAllpersons() in my code , but I have no idea where I'd need to put it.

```js
.controller('personsCtrl', ['$scope', 'personSrv', function personsCtrl($scope, personSrv) {
    personSrv.getAllpersons().success(response){
      $scope.persons  = response.data.rows;
    }
}])
```

Comment: Where is personSrv.getAllpersons() getting it's data from? I ran into a similar issue when I didn't realize the data was coming from a JSONP service and was trying to call a callback

Answer (score 1):

```
personSrv.getAllpersons().success(response){
  $scope.persons  = response.data.rows;
}
```

The code snippet above contains an incorrect function expression, you are missing the important keywords. This would be correct:

```
personSrv.getAllpersons().success(function(response){
  $scope.persons  = response.data.rows;
})
```

However keep in mind that `.success` is deprecated and should not be used.

**Edit:**
Instead of `.success(SUCCESS-CB)` consider using `.then(SUCCESS-CB, ERROR-CB)` or even `.then(SUCCESS-CB).catch(ERROR-CB)`. Personally, I prefer the last one as it is easy on the eyes.